# Songs similar to 'Tuyo' from Rodrigo Amarante

Tags: similar-artists, identify-this-genre

Do you know any songs similar to [*Tuyo*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcve1Tn3VYs) from the singer Rodrigo Amarante? It's the opening credits theme song of Netflix serie Narcos.

Answer (score 7):

Note that Rodrigo Amarante, is a Brasillian singer who usually sings in Brasilian portuguese, but sings in spanish on this song.

I think the genre is **Latin America Bolero**. The song is in 4/4 time but, I feel like I want to move like a walz and "attach" the 1 and 2. The time signature is

```
||  1   |   2  |   3   |   4   ||
|| Ooooooooone |  Two  | Three ||
```

You can listen to the Ecuadorian singer **Julio Jaramillo** and these songs: [*Nuestro Juramento*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZRv-l9L1J0), [*Te Odio Y Te Quiero*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVIpoVbeRLE) or [*De Cigarro En Cigarro*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hj_o9M951xQ) from the album [*Colección de Oro*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZRv-l9L1J0&list=PLWS5ls9eXME0fJ0kxMagaqd9oSJozF_9G).

Also the Mexican band **Los Panchos** specialized in romantic latin bolero: [*Sabor a Mi*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQCo3rczB-w), [*Historia de un amor*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=12&v=HSpIE6CN63w)

Comment: Great answer, Bebs --I know genres are not your specialty, but I do think you've nailed it this time.  With that said, I think you mean the *Cuban* bolero, not the Spanish one --your (excellent) examples are all of the Latin (Cuban) version, and it's that version that has the 4/4 beat, not the [Spanish one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9R31XxzzGzQ), see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolero).

Comment: @ChrisSunami, you are correct. Thanks for the clarification. btw I like talking about general and classic genres. What I don't like is to discuss about sub-sub-genre-crossed-with-under-sub-style-of-whatever... :-)

Comment: I have to say I track down good advice on internet. I rarely find something so well advised as this Bebs post.  Well explained and great examples. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @A.Dumas, thanks for your support. Unfortunately, it seems that OP has left a long time ago.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer. Do you have additional recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

The song [*Dulcito e Coco*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTrUFzZi-TM) (2017) by the Dominican singer [**Vicente García**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicente_Garc%C3%ADa_(musician)) also has a Bolero feel, even this is not the only genre he plays.

Answer (score 1):

For excellent acoustic music of same general rhythm and sensibility, I would recommend music of the *[Buena Vista Social Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buena_Vista_Social_Club),* and its associated musicians.

The album of the same title was a popular revival, with the original musicians, of the elegant pre-revolutionary Cuban sound, including the subgenres of *trova,* *filin,* *son cubano,* *bolero* and *danzón*.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNYOVEXJBBM

Answer (score 0):

Mondo Bongo - Joe Strummer & The Mescaleros it's the same genre.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPjaXu6g1Xk